# textFieldShouldBeginEditing is called repeatedly only in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield

I have two textfield(name and phone#).Once user is registered, user should not able to edit phone number textfield. I am checking the condition when user click on phone number textfield. if registered I am creating alert saying that "Cannot edit". When i click on "ok" i dismiss the keypad. I am using the following code to do so

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
 if(registered)
 {
   dismissAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"cannot edit" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [dismissAlert show];
 }
}

if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
{
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
   [self.PhoneNumber resignFirstResponder];
   dismissAlert = nil;
}
```

But textFieldShouldBeginEditing called multiple times. It happens only in iPad.

Comment: Are you calling `[self.PhoneNumber becomeFirstResponder];` somewhere that may be called twice?

Comment: no, i am not calling self.buddyPhoneNumber.

Comment: Why are you calling ```endEditing``` and ```resignFirstResponder```?
Remove those lines and it will work.

Comment: @Fabio Berger If i am not calling endEditing and resignFirstResponder, keypad gets appeard.

Comment: @elavarasan well you might want to show it, don't you? 
But if you want the keyboard to be hidden, just ```return NO;```instead of ```endEditing``` and ```resignFirstResponder``` and the keyboard will not appear

Comment: well i am unable to see any `BOOL`, that must `NO` (if you don't want to edit for textField) at the end of method or in any `if Condition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got it. I set

```
self.PhoneNumber.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == txtPhone)
    {
         [self performSelector:@selector(phoneAlert) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
         return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)phoneAlert
{
     dismissAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"cannot edit" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [dismissAlert show];
}
```